# What exactly is required for Apple's Find-my-car feature to work?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, maps

My friends and I have noticed inconsistent results with Apple's feature to find your parked car. We've all seen it work sometimes, but not always.

The feature I'm talking about is described here: http://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/06/14/apple-maps-ios-10-parking/

As I understand it, you must have Car Play or Bluetooth in your car, you must have iOS 10.x or greater, and have Apple Maps installed. Beyond that, how does this work?

I've tried a couple of times lately to test this, making sure that Bluetooth is connected during the trip. After arriving, I can ask Siri: "Where's my car?" and I get:

*Sorry, I don't see any saved parking locations.*

It seemed to be working reliably for a user with Car Play.  Is that required?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must have a CarPlay device & the iPhone must connect to it when you get in the car & disconnect as you leave.
That is the trigger to update your Parked Location.

It works over either direct connection on Lightning cable, or using Bluetooth, though if your CarPlay is set to Lightning, it will not update if you have Bluetooth on, but don't manually switch to it - CarPlay does not 'auto-swap' to Bluetooth if you don't plug it in.

Apple documents this here:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207227

The location privacy can show you frequent locations as well as parked locations, so if you have disabled that location tracking, you could expect maps to not mark your Bluetooth disconnect locations. Also, not pairing to Bluetooth would likely prevent is feature from working

(Information source in addition to above is personal experience & wondering how the heck it sometimes worked & sometimes didn't ;)

Comment: I think I have everything turned on as required in that Apple article. I do have Bluetooth in the car, but not Car Play. So far, it hasn't been working for me. I'm going to have to experiment with this.

Comment: But if I understand this answer correctly you must have CarPlay and you say you do not, so why do you think it should work for you? Or do I misunderstand the answer?

Comment: bmike added the Apple KB link which I hadn't previously seen. I've never had a unit in a vehicle with only Bluetooth & not CarPlay, so I can't say for certain, but it does look like it might work with only Bluetooth. I'd be tempted to say it could depend on the specific car system as to whether it's going to be fully functional or not.

Comment: T. H. I think it should work for me without Car Play because the Apple article linked in the answer says "Bluetooth or Car Play" and "Car Play or Bluetooth".

Comment: I'm in a vehicle this week which I think has bluetooth, it certainly doesn't have CarPlay. I'll test it if I remember...

Comment: @Tetsujin I rented a Toyota car in Japan, which had bluetooth, but not, as far as I am aware, Car Play. I didn’t even know about Find My Car until I paired my phone with the car stereo and found the location appearing on the maps. Worked brilliantly, and I am now trying to find a solution for my old car at home.

Comment: @Manngo - I completely forgot to check, last year :/ My car has a CarPlay unit, which I faithfully USB to as I get in. If I don't, I don't *think* I see a 'parked' update... but tbh I'm not really paying sufficient attention to find a pattern. I generally am reasonably aware of where I parked - I even take photos if it's huge, like an airport car park.